Custom package install leads to subprocess.CalledProcessError -> No module named pip
Important(?) Details

Windows 10, version 10.0.19045
Python 3.12.2
PyCharm 2024.1 (Professional Edition)
GitBash 2.45.1.windows.1

The Setup
I'm trying to install pygraphviz with my package in a virtual environment.
I've written a custom install subclass to be used by setuptools during package install.
"""Contents of custom_install.py"""

from os import getenv
from platform import system
import subprocess
import sys

from setuptools.command.install import install


class InstallPygraphviz(install):
    """Custom command to install pygraphviz package.

    Reference:
    https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html#windows
    """

    def run(self):
        python_exe = sys.executable
        subprocess.check_call([python_exe, "-m", "ensurepip"])
        pip_command = [python_exe, "-m", "pip", "install"]
        if system() == "Windows":
            graphviz_path = getenv("GRAPHVIZ_PATH")
            if graphviz_path is None:
                raise ValueError("GRAPHVIZ_PATH is not set")

            include_path = f"{graphviz_path}/include"
            lib_path = f"{graphviz_path}/lib"
            pip_command.extend(
                [
                    "--config-settings='--global-option=build_ext'",
                    f"--config-settings='--global-option=-I{include_path}'",
                    f"--config-settings='--global-option=-L{lib_path}'",
                ]
            )

        pip_command.append("pygraphviz")
        subprocess.check_call(pip_command)
        install.run(self)


Per this github issue, I learned I could use a pyproject.toml to set my config settings instead of setup.py.
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=70.0.0", "setuptools-scm>=8.1.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "awesome"
requires-python = ">=3.12"
dynamic = ["version"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "awesome.__version__"}

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[tool.setuptools.cmdclass]
install = "awesome.custom_install.InstallPygraphviz"

This is my package layout:
pyproject.toml     
+---src
    +---awesome
    |   |   custom_install.py
    |   |   __init__.py

Recreating The Problem

I create and activate a virtual environment:
py -3.12 -m venv env

source env/Scripts/activate


I cd into the project directory and run the following command:
pip install .


Errors
Processing c:\users\user\ado\test
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: awesome
  Building wheel for awesome (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for awesome (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [66 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib
      creating build\lib\awesome
      copying src\awesome\custom_install.py -> build\lib\awesome
      copying src\awesome\__init__.py -> build\lib\awesome
      running egg_info
      writing src\awesome.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\awesome.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src\awesome.egg-info\top_level.txt
      ERROR setuptools_scm._file_finders.git listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
      reading manifest file 'src\awesome.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      writing manifest file 'src\awesome.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
      running install
      Looking in links: c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyagl6bqz
      Processing c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmpyagl6bqz\pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl
      Installing collected packages: pip
      Successfully installed pip-24.0
      C:\Users\user\ADO\test\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\ADO\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\user\ADO\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\ADO\test\env\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel        
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 395, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 200, in run_commands  
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands  
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 968, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command   
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\normal\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 403, in run
          self.run_command("install")
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command    
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 968, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pbo1oi67\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command   
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\user\ADO\test\src\awesome\custom_install.py", line 38, in run
          subprocess.check_call(pip_command)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\user\\ADO\\test\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', "--config-settings='--global-option=build_ext'", "--config-settings='--global-option=-IC:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Graphviz/include'", "--config-settings='--global-option=-LC:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Graphviz/lib'", 'pygraphviz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for awesome
Failed to build awesome
ERROR: Could not build wheels for awesome, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects



Looking through the traceback I found this:
C:\Users\user\ADO\test\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip

Not sure how that's possible as I believe pip comes with the virtual environment.
But to be sure, I run the following at the top of :method:InstallPygraphviz.run:
def run(self):
    python_exe = sys.executable
    subprocess.check_call([python_exe, "-m", "ensurepip"])
    ...

This passes, as noted in the traceback just before it errors:
...
running install
Looking in links: c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyagl6bqz
Processing c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmpyagl6bqz\pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-24.0
C:\Users\user\ADO\test\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
...

I'm at a loss for what to do. Running the code in :method:InstallPygraphviz.run in an interpreter works just fine, as does running the commands within the pip_command in git-bash.
How do I tell subprocess that pip exists in the environment and it should use it?

When you run pip install ., pip creates a minimal and ephemeral virtual environment to build the project, likely there is no pip in that environment. -- What is the actual goal? Seems like you are trying to shoehorn things into setup.py that are out of scope for setup.py.

@sinoroc that explains all the temp directory stuff in the logs. I'm trying to add pygraphviz as a dependency to a project that may be installed on Windows. If you look at the link I referenced in the class doc strong you'll see that installing on Windows requires additional arguments be provided to pip. I'm trying to handle all of this in setup.py if possible.

"I'm trying to handle all of this in setup.py if possible." I wouldn't bother if I were you. It is not your responsibility to fix issues in other packages. -- Also, this is not what setup.py is for, so in my opinion this is the wrong way to address this anyway. -- The best you can do is document things properly for your users, provide them the link you mentioned, and it is up to them to install things. You should not make assumptions on how your users want to install things. Doing things behind their back in setup.py is bad, in my opinion.

There is one more thing... You should not assume that the setup.py file is going to be used at each installation. Typically pip, builds a wheel on the first installation (this uses the setup.py), but for subsequent installations pip installs directly from the wheel that it build earlier, so the setup.py is not used at all.

@sinoroc that makes sense. I ended up switching to pydot instead of pygraphviz so I won't need the custom setup.py anymore. Thanks for being a sounding board!

I was able to recreate the issue like with your code.
(env) PS C:\Users\bkcmk5\Desktop\Projects_for_portfolio\python_test> pip install .   

Processing c:\users\bkcmk5\desktop\projects_for_portfolio\python_test
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: awesome
Building wheel for awesome (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for awesome (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [63 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
copying src\awesome\custom_install.py -> build\lib\awesome
copying src\awesome_init_.py -> build\lib\awesome
running egg_info
writing src\awesome.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\awesome.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to src\awesome.egg-info\top_level.txt
ERROR setuptools_scm._file_finders.git listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
reading manifest file 'src\awesome.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'src\awesome.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
running install
Looking in links: c:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6vkm3k87
Processing c:\users\bkcmk5\appdata\local\temp\tmp6vkm3k87\pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-24.0
C:\Users\bkcmk5\Desktop\Projects_for_portfolio\python_test\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\Desktop\Projects_for_portfolio\python_test\env\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\Desktop\Projects_for_portfolio\python_test\env\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\Desktop\Projects_for_portfolio\python_test\env\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel
return self._build_with_temp_dir(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 395, in build_with_temp_dir
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_init.py", line 103, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py", line 184, in setup
return run_commands(dist)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py", line 200, in run_commands
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 968, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 403, in run
self.run_command("install")
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 968, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97xc4m16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\Desktop\Projects_for_portfolio\python_test\src\awesome\custom_install.py", line 36, in run
subprocess.check_call(pip_command)
File "C:\Users\bkcmk5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\Users\bkcmk5\Desktop\Projects_for_portfolio\python_test\env\Scripts\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', "--config-settings='--global-option=build_ext'", "--config-settings='--global-option=-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz/include'", "--config-settings='--global-option=-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz/lib'", 'pygraphviz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for awesome
Failed to build awesome
ERROR: Could not build wheels for awesome, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I was able to get around this by installing in the editable mode (-e) of pip.
pip install -e . 

Solved the issue, and was able to install the code. I checked first for Python and corresponding versions in the virtual environment, then added the system variable in the Windows environment.

Unfortunately this doesn't actually run the custom install command because pip isntall -e . invokes the develop command instead of the install command in setuptools. You can verify by running pip show pygraphviz.
