How to specify system-dependent versions of dependent libraries with pyproject.toml
I am creating a library named mygeo that depends on a GDAL python package.
To install the gdal python library, we must specify the same version of GDAL that is installed on the system, like as follows:
ref: https://gdal.org/api/python_bindings.html#pip
pip install gdal[numpy]=="$(gdal-config --version).*"

I tried to use a tool.setuptools.cmdclass feature with following pyproject.toml.
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"


[project]
name = "mygeo"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = [
    { name = "me", email = "me@example.com" }
]
dependencies = [
    # It works if I hard code version of the GDAL here.
    # gdal==3.5.1
    # other dependencies come here..
]
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">= 3.8"

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules=["_custom_build"]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.cmdclass]
install="_custom_build.install"

The above pyproject.toml run scripts in install.run() in _custom_build.py.
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install
import ensurepip
import subprocess
import sys

class install(_install):
    def run(self):
        ensurepip.bootstrap()
        try:
            # get gdal version
            gdal_version = (
                subprocess.check_output(["gdal-config", "--version"]).decode().strip()
            )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(f"Error obtaining GDAL version: {e}")
            sys.exit(1)

        try:
            # Install gdal with pip install
            result = subprocess.run(
                [sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", f"gdal=={gdal_version}"],
                capture_output=True,
                text=True,
                check=True
            )
            print(result.stdout)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(f"Error installing GDAL: {e}")
            print(f"stdout: {e.stdout}")
            print(f"stderr: {e.stderr}")
            sys.exit(1)

        _install.run(self)

I confirmed that subprocess to get gdal version is running when user pip install . in the project directory.
But, following subprocess to install gdal with pip did not work.
The error message was as follows.
(.venv) ubuntu@3ff8353192c9:~/work/mygeo$ pip install .
Processing /home/ubuntu/work/mygeo
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mygeo
  Building wheel for mygeo (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for mygeo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      copying _custom_build.py -> build/lib
      running egg_info
      writing mygeo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to mygeo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to mygeo.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'mygeo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'mygeo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
      running install
      Looking in links: /tmp/tmpe02gnju5
      Processing /tmp/tmpe02gnju5/pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl
      Installing collected packages: pip
      Successfully installed pip-24.0
      Error installing GDAL: Command '['/home/ubuntu/work/mygeo/.venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'gdal==3.8.4']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      stdout:
      stderr: /home/ubuntu/work/mygeo/.venv/bin/python: No module named pip

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mygeo
Failed to build mygeo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mygeo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Run pip install gdal==3.8.4 in .venv manually, or hard code the version on pyproject.toml.
Is it possible to use the cmdclass functionality to automatically install a dependency library of the appropriate version for the user's environment?
The version of GDAL installed on the system varies from user to user.
Is there any other way to dynamically specify the version obtained by the script gdal-config --version?

You should be able to capture the specific system error associated with subprocess "non-zero exit status 1". What does this say?

I updated _custom_build.py script to capture error messages from subprocess, and added the error message which I got.

You cannot solve this. There is no way. -- Note that setup.py is not always used. Notably it is not used when installing from a wheel. When installing from a sdist, pip first builds a wheel, then installs that wheel. Subsequent installations use directly the wheel, and setup.py is not used at all. -- I do not believe this is something you can solve with tricks like this one you are attempting. The only clean solution I know of, is to document things properly and let your users install things the way they want to install things.

See also the comments on this somewhat loosely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78582914
